# Skip checkout process in Shopify

Tags: shopify, checkout

I have Shopify website. I don't want the checkout process. Instead of that in cart page, I want to capture the cart record and customer address, when the person click the place order button in cart page.

I don't have worked much things in Shopify.

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site.What have you tried? No one knows what your requirements are, and you are basically asking for an entire solution. This will not get much traction. Start writing some code and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @jdv SO is a place to get help which he came to do. Also, Anybody familiar with Shopify development would have known how to answer the question. I've heard that SO is often a hostile place, try not to contribute to that.

Comment: @pfcodes the subject doesn't matter. As per [ask] we have guidelines for good questions that you are encouraged to at least consider. [SO] is a place to ask well-formed questions to build a body of QA for _everyone_, not just a single person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to create a private app with permissions to the store's Shopify Admin API to handle that logic.

Also, in the cart template, you're going to have to disable the cart form altogether to prevent going to the checkout gateway and use JavaScript to submit the route form's information to the handler of your private app where it will process the cart record and customer information and then store it in a local data store.